# How convert JSON to POJO Kotlin

Tags: java, android, json, kotlin

I have a JSON file that contains product categories. I'm trying to convert the resulting JSON file to Kotlin classes so that I can show the resulting data in RecyclerView in the future. I created the necessary POJO classes, in the logs I see that I get the correct data from the server. But when I try to log data from Fragment I see that my data is null. How can I solve this problem?
Example JSON:

```
{
  "beauty_health": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "brand": "Kaya Youth",
      "category": "Beauty & Health",
      "name": "Hydro Replenish Face Wash",
      "description": "Hydro Replenish Face Wash, With Aloe Vera",
      "price": 42,
      "icon": ""
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "brand": "Kaya Youth",
      "category": "Beauty & Health",
      "name": "Oxy-Infusion Face Wash",
      "description": "Kaya Youth Oxy-Infusion Face Wash,100",
      "price": 18,
      "icon": ""
    }],
  "electronics": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "brand": "OnePlus",
      "category": "Electronics",
      "name": "OnePlus 8",
      "description": "OnePlus 8T 64GB",
      "price": 250,
      "icon": ""
    },],
```

POJO classes example:

// ProductList class

```
data class ProductList(
    @SerializedName("beauty_health")
    var beautyHealth: List<BeautyHealth>,
    @SerializedName("electronics")
    val electronics: List<Electronic>,
    @SerializedName("fashion")
    val fashion: List<Fashion>,
    @SerializedName("image_slider")
    val imageSlider: List<ImageSlider>,
    @SerializedName("popular")
    val popular: List<Popular>,
    @SerializedName("sports")
    val sports: List<Sport>) : Serializable
```

// Beauty Health class

```
data class BeautyHealth(
    @SerializedName("brand")
    val brand: String,
    @SerializedName("category")
    val category: String,
    @SerializedName("description")
    val description: String,
    @SerializedName("icon")
    val icon: String,
    @SerializedName("id")
    val id: Int,
    @SerializedName("name")
    var name: String,
    @SerializedName("price")
    val price: Int) : Serializable
```

My repository:

```
api.onFetchAllProducts().enqueue(object : Callback<ProductList> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ProductList>, t: Throwable) {
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<ProductList>, response: Response<ProductList>) {

                mutableLiveData.postValue(response.body())
            }
        })
        return mutableLiveData
```

My ViewModel:

```
fun onGetProductsList(): MutableLiveData<ProductList> {
        return apiRepository.onLoadProducts()
    }
```

And my Fragment:

```
mHomeViewModel.onGetProductsList().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { products ->

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: $products")
    })
```

My logs:

```
D/HomeFragment: onCreateView: null
```

Comment: your `onFailure` is empty, how do you know the call is even successful ?

Comment: I see in OkHttp logging interseptor

Comment: just use this to covert gson into model class Gson().fromJson(your gson,POJO::class;java)

Comment: There are several tools served to simplify json to pojo class automatic transformation. https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/# - for verifying and pretty printing your json, https://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ - automatically transforms json to pojo classes (java), https://www.json2kt.com/ - automatically transforms json to kotlin data classes, similar to pojo class, but because it is in kotlin this abbreviation becomes misleading (POJO means plain old **java** object)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Kotlin's `data class` as your `Gson` model, **you must give default values to all properties**.

In Java, all Objects have default null values. If you choose to use a Kotlin data class as a model with non-null properties and you're missing one of the fields in the JSON response, the whole serialization will fail.

So for example, try to change this:

```
data class BeautyHealth(
    @SerializedName("brand")
    val brand: String,
    @SerializedName("category")
    val category: String,
    @SerializedName("description")
    val description: String,
    @SerializedName("icon")
    val icon: String,
    @SerializedName("id")
    val id: Int,
    @SerializedName("name")
    var name: String,
    @SerializedName("price")
    val price: Int) : Serializable
```

to:

```
data class BeautyHealth(
    @SerializedName("brand")
    val brand: String = "",
    @SerializedName("category")
    val category: String = "",
    @SerializedName("description")
    val description: String = "",
    @SerializedName("icon")
    val icon: String = "",
    @SerializedName("id")
    val id: Int = 0,
    @SerializedName("name")
    var name: String = "",
    @SerializedName("price")
    val price: Int = 0) : Serializable
```

Comment: That's not my problem. in OnFailure I get an error saying that -> onFailure: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $ . But I don't want to get a List<Product List>. I want to get <ProductList> and add my categories from JSON to the Product List. but I don't know how to do it